# The difference between 3 digit number and reversing its digit is always divisible by

Tags: divisibility

The difference between a 3 digit number and a number fomed by reversing its digit is always divisible by?

a.6

b.9

c.12

d.19

How to approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number thus formed is divisible by 9

Answer (score 1):

Let $100a + 10b + c$ be your number; its reverse is $100c + 10b + a$.

Subtracting:
$$\begin{aligned}
(100a + 10b + c) - (100c + 10b + a) &= (100-1)a + (10-10)b + (1-100)c \\
&= 99a - 99c\\
&= 99(a-c)
\end{aligned}$$

So it is always divisible by $99$, and in particular, $9$.